# Does the googleapis's list_tasks include the running tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task-queue, google-cloud-tasks

I am using the [googleapis.dev](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/tasks_v2/cloud_tasks.html) to connect with my cloud task queue. I want to make sure that the queue is empty and the tasks are done. The question is, does the "list_tasks" function return only the scheduled tasks, or does it also include that tasks that are currently **running**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API suggests performing a list on the tasks in a queue will return an array of tasks like so:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      object (Task)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

An example task object is like so:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "scheduleTime": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "dispatchDeadline": string,
  "dispatchCount": integer,
  "responseCount": integer,
  "firstAttempt": {
    object (Attempt)
  },
  "lastAttempt": {
    object (Attempt)
  },
  "view": enum (View),

  // Union field payload_type can be only one of the following:
  "appEngineHttpRequest": {
    object (AppEngineHttpRequest)
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    object (HttpRequest)
  },
  "pullMessage": {
    object (PullMessage)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field payload_type.
}
```

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task) :

> If responseTime is unset, then the task has not been attempted or is **currently running** and the responseStatus field is meaningless.

TL;DR **Yes, running tasks are displayed**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So the running tasks are not only displayed (I can see the queued and running cloumns in gcp cloud task UI), but also returned in the list_tasks call. In all my tries, I never saw the "firstAttempt" returned in the list_tasks. I just want to be sure.

Comment: In order to confirm this, I did some tests and saw that it is true! Thank you.